# How to Build LINQ for this SQL Statement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I trying to build a LINQ statment to meet this SQL statement.

```
 SELECT * FROM [Access].[14 MATERIAL_LIST] WHERE MATERIAL_DESC LIKE
 '%GASKET%300%30%';
```

I already try like using loop. and the linq will produce like this.

```
 SELECT * FROM [Access].[14 MATERIAL_LIST] WHERE MATERIAL_DESC LIKE
 '%GASKET%' AND MATERIAL_DESC LIKE '%300%' AND MATERIAL_DESC LIKE
 '%30%';
```

Loop statement

```
foreach (var item in tanoList) {
    QueryML = QueryML.Where(z => z.Material_Desc.Contains(item)); }
```

Comment: The SQL query is equivalent to a single `QueryML.Where(z => z.Material_Desc.Contains("GASKET%300%30"))`. LINQ won't generate what you posted, it will surround the predicate with `%`, producing your original expression. Why use loops at all?

Comment: loop to generate multiple .contain(item) in the statement.

Comment: I repeat, the question only has *one* value. If you want to search for multiple values say so explicitly in the question. People can't answer a question you haven't asked.

Comment: What values are stored inside `tanoList`?. Are you using EF Core?

Answer (score 1):

You should approach the problem reversely. This will get you there;

```
QueryML.Where(z =>tanoList.Any(item =>z.Material_Desc.Contains(item)));
```

Comment: Can plz convert this sql statement to LINQ  "SELECT * FROM [Access].[14 MATERIAL_LIST] WHERE MATERIAL_DESC LIKE
 '%GASKET%300%30%';"

Comment: Let me see, we are actually looking for a custom string comparison

Comment: im trying to produce LIKE ''%GASKET%300%30%'" statement using LINQ.